# How to "hide" a row in Oracle SQL database but not delete it

Tags: c#, sql, database, oracle

Is there a way to "hide" a row in Oracle SQL database without deleting it, So that it is still in the database but does not show up on the webpage as a search result?

For example, I want to hide a specific city in my database from being displayed in the results when searching for cities on the webpage.

Comment: Why not just modify your query to have something like `...where city_name <> 'New York City'`

Comment: Because that is not my task assigned to me. I need to hide the entire row.

Comment: Can you just filter it out after returning it? Ideally you wouldn't waste time retrieving a record that you don't want, but if you absolutely have to, you could filter out that record using LINQ or your own custom code. Something like ``var filteredResults = results.Where(x => x.CityName != 'New York City')``

Comment: It's unclear from the question what exactly the purpose of hiding the specific row is. There are multiple ways you can do this, including those already listed in the answers below. If it's security related, you might consider Row Level Security (Virtual Private Database - VPD).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a column to the table with a flag as to whether to show or hide the row and then add a `WHERE` filter to your query to filter out rows where the row should be hidden.

If you have the table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE cities (name) AS
SELECT 'Berlin'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Lisbon'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Prague'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Amsterdam' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Kiev'      FROM DUAL;
```

Then you can do something like:

```sql
ALTER TABLE cities
  ADD visibility NUMBER(1,0)
                 INVISIBLE
                 DEFAULT 1
  CONSTRAINT cities__visibility__chk CHECK (visibility IN (0,1));
```

*(Note: `INVISIBLE` will cause a column not to be shown when you use `SELECT * FROM cities`, it can still be shown if you name the columns `SELECT name, visibility FROM cities`.)*

Then set a row to not be visible:

```sql
UPDATE cities
SET    visibility = 0
WHERE  name = 'Amsterdam';
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   cities
WHERE  visibility = 1;
```

Outputs:

> | NAME |
> | --- |
> | Berlin |
> | Lisbon |
> | Prague |
> | Kiev |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=03f76edc12af21520b4865359e21c05b)*

Comment: Alright, thank you, this helps significantly. I appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

@MR0 's solution is great, but depending on your availability requirement (i.e., whether downtime is available), you can consider hidding the `VISIBILITY` column inside a view, instead of using an `INVISIBLE` attribute.

```
ALTER TABLE cities RENAME to cities_table;

CREATE VIEW cities AS
SELECT name FROM cities_table
WHERE visibility = 1;

-- copy privileges of cities_table to cities view
GRANT SELECT ON cities TO user1; 
...
```

Pros:

1. No change to existing code using `CITIES`

Cons:

1. `CITIES` becomes unavailable between rename table and privilege granted
2. Many objects depending on `CITIES` would become invalid. But Oracle should automatically recompile them upon use.
3. DDL assuming `CITIES` is table will fail (e.g., `TRUNCATE TABLE CITIES;`)
4. Need to modify both the view and the table when adding columns
5. Potential performance impact for view parsing (should be undetectable)

While there are many cons, the single pro may outweigh the cons,
depending on actual situation.

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=885ae44ee87f8101b1b0d9f9f68ceeee)